# convert string array to array php

Tags: php, arrays, string, associative

I have string like this

```
{"status":"2","holding":"","company":"Company","nik":"8981237","name":"Markonah","ownercard":"Istri"}
```

how to convert this string to associative array in PHP

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its JSON, to convert to array use `json_decode()`:

```
$string = '{"status":"2","holding":"","company":"Company","nik":"8981237","name":"Markonah","ownercard":"Istri"}';
$my_array = json_decode($string,true);
echo $my_array["status"]; // output: 2
```

Comment: Probably better to perform a var_dump($my_array) or print_r($my_array) to allow the OP to see the complete array. Also json_decode returns an object so you would use $my_array->status. And you are missing a ; semi-colon on the end of $string.

Comment: To return an associative array you would use json_decode($string, true); Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @AhmadSopian If this solved your issue, please click the 'checkmark' to accept this answer.